# Compiling Server Application OPC UA

Tags: xml, opc-ua, node-set, .csproj.in

I´ve compiled an information model and created a .csproj and .xml file with the UA_Modeler. Afterward I´ve tried to start a server with two different approaches:

1.)
Following these instructions:
https://documentation.unified-automation.com/uamodeler/1.6.7/html/howgennetserver_sec.html,
when running the .csproj file with VisualStudio22 an error is showing up, that the debug file: test.exe is not exisisting.

2.)
Converting the .xml into a NodeSet2.xml using the UA Model Compiler,
which is showing an error by the time using the Compiler with the MS PowerShell, which says "-d2" command is unknown.

Does someone know a solution for that specific issue?

Thanks!